# arrayformula + filter + join function problem

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets 1st sheet contain email address and apps column A -> email and column B -> apps and the emails in column A are not unique they are repeated with different apps.
In 2nd sheet i am extracting the emails with unique formula and I want to have all the comments related to the email in single cell "," separated.
= =iferror(regexmatch(join(",",filter(Sheet1!$B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$2:$A=$A2)),$C$1),"")[This is how the table will look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te5Bz.jpg) 
But I have to manually drag the formula to the entire column and cannot use Ctrl+Shift+enter because the emails will be automatically be added. **Thus want to use array formula.** But I am not able to get the right array formula. Can anybody help.

Comment: Can you share (a copy of) your spreadsheet so that we have some data to work with?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result